# INavigationAware Does not work on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I was playing around with INavigationAware and OnNavigatedFrom,OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatingTo .

I have two pages with prism MVVM . The first page I implemented the INavigationAware in the viewModel and it works fine .

but the second page , I was doing some testing and implemented INavigationAware  in the code behind of the view its self and it worked fine But when I removed it from there and moved it to the ViewModel it does not work . and I made sure of this

```
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

I tried to clean the solution but that did not help

Both pages are registered like this :

```
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
// the page that does not work 
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MerchantPage,MerchantPageViewModel>();
```

Secondpage ViewModel can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/alkharashiam/c75f3c913f03f6e43c0000dbc805f670

Comment: You should also share your VMs code

Comment: @TaiT's just updated my question to include it.

Comment: Would help if you post AppMapViewModelBase as well @user2596181

Comment: @TaiT's https://gist.github.com/alkharashiam/b249d41f2797e41601075ca5f38352c6

I used AppMap and appmap auto generated this for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with the code that I think were probably generated during your different tests as I can see `INavigationAware` commented out in the base ViewModel but the implementation is still there.

Which at this point I guess it's calling the base Methods instead of the `MerchantPageViewModel`'s. You can put a break point in the base method and see if it passes by there. Probably just by using `override` keyword in your OnNavigatedXXX(..) methods will do it.

Anyway I would clean it up your code this way:

1. Keep the base viewModel implementing INavigationAware interface

   ```
   public abstract class AppMapViewModelBase : BindableBase, IDestructible, INavigationAware
   ```
2. remove the  `private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;` from `MerchantPageViewModel` and just pass on the navigtionService to the base constructor

   ```
   public MerchantPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
   {
       // _navigationService = navigationService; removed
   }
   ```
3. remove the `INavigationAware` from `MerchantPageViewModel` declaration since it's already implemented by the base class

   ```
   internal class MerchantPageViewModel : AppMapViewModelBase //, INavigationAware removed
   ```
4. override your methods this way in the `MerchantPageViewModel`:

   ```
   public override void OnNavigatedFrom(INavigationParameters parameters)
   {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
   {
       //throw new NotImplementedException();
       Merchant = parameters.GetValue<Merchant>("merchant");
       Debug.WriteLine(Merchant.MerhcnatName);
   }

   public override void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
   {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
   ```
5. If you need to navigate pages from an a child ViewModel, just use `NavigationService` from the base class like that:

   ```
   await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(...);
   ```

Hope it's clear!

Happy coding!

Comment: I will give it a try , but the thing is both page one and page two use the same base model but for page one it works fine and for page two it does not work and even if i set a breakpoint inside OnNavigatedTo of the second page it does not pass by it..

Comment: hmmm after further investigation even simple label binding with a string in vm does not work .. it looks like the view and viewmodel is not binding even though          prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
is set

Comment: is binding tabbpedpage to a ViewModel any different than contentPage ?

Comment: I feel stupid ... Apparently I had this in my view that binded to another ViewModel 
    <TabbedPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:CardsSampleViewModel/>
    </TabbedPage.BindingContext>
I removed it and everything worked fine .

Comment: No worries it happens. But hard to figure out on my side without all the sources ;). Anyway you can still think about refactoring a little bit the code cause you have spread some navigation stuffs all over. Happy coding!

Comment: of course , im refactoring right now because most of the code was Auto Generated from AppMap